# Redshift does not support correlated subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, amazon-redshift

I am trying to run sql that runs on Postgresql but when I try on our Redshift db I get an error

> > ERROR:  This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet

What I am trying to do, is for all roles that, find the number of days in the 30 days before the role startdate that had roles, at all the sites within 20km of that site.

I just cant see how to do this differently... any ideas would be amazing!

```
select 
    roles.id,
    roles.start_date,
    roles.site_id
    ,(SELECT 
        count(*) 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            rl.start_date,
            sum(rl.amount)
            FROM roles rl
            WHERE rl.site_id IN
                 (SELECT 
                    site_id_end
                    from all_view.site_distances 
                    where distance_km <= 20 
                    and site_id_start = roles.site_id)           
            AND rl.start_date between (roles.start_date - interval '29 days') and roles.start_date
            GROUP BY 1) as days_with_roles
        )
from   
    roles as roles
where 
    roles.site_id = 123
```

Comment: I think your query can be rewritten with `WITH` clause. But need sample data and sample output.

Comment: You need to convert the subqueries to joins. Difficult to provide a concrete example with some data samples.

Comment: thanks for the responses.  I'll try and get some data samples